# Encrypt/Mask sensitive data on git push (Encryprted/masked display on remote repo)

Tags: typescript, git, cypress

I have a Cypress code that contains sensitive header that I wish to be masked/decrypted

```js
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://sample-url',
    headers: {
        'key': 'value'
    }
})
```

Is there a way whenever we push on remote, my desired values gets encrypted (e.g. the headers on the above example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing I can think of that will encrypt and decrypt values automatically via git push/fetch. That's probably not the direction you want to go anyway.

The more simple way dealing with sensitive values is by storing them in environment variables and to not commit these to version control.

With Cypress, there's several ways to [get environment vars into tests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables), but one easy way is with a `cypress.env.json` file. This file would be listed inside your .gitignore.

The env file would look like the following:

```js
// cypress.env.json
{
  "secretKey": "value"
}
```

And your code would call it like this

```js
// Code
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://sample-url',
    headers: {
        'key': Cypress.env('secretKey');
    }
})
```

The only thing you need to make sure, if you run the tests in a pipeline, you have to set the environmet variables before running the tests.

Here's another link that I think could help

https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/keep-passwords-secret-in-e2e-tests/

Comment: This works on my end. Just a quick follow-up, we are planning to put all of our *sensitive* data in a JSON file. Is there a way to use `Cypress.env('value')` values in a JSON file? Not sure if this one is still within the bounds of my question

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean by using `Cypress.env('value')` values in json files.

Comment: Ooh, nevermind, I see the idea. Your approach is much easier to do. Thanks